# How to modify the skin color and background of the installer generated using Install-shield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012, installshield-2010, installshield-2011, installshield-2009

I am new to Install Shield. Trying to modify the new installer background and the color of the installer panel. How to customize the skin, background color or add background image for the new installer generated using Installshield 2010.

I tried to modify the skin preview .bmp image of the IS but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own images in IS's Support\Themes.  Banner.jpg [499x58], Banner_mirror.jpg [499x58], preview.jpg [504x386], setup.gif [166x315], Welcome.jpg [499x312] and Welcome_mirror.jpg [499x312]. Mirror images are optional in case of right to left language. Reference Class Theme folder for sample preview.jpg.

Copy Classic.theme from InstallShield's Support\Themes folder and paste it as CustomTheme.theme. Open file in Notepad and change theme name to your custom name and update the path for your images. Then, open InstallShield.  New theme should display under User Interface > Dialogs > Themes. Right-click to select.